# Adding a column with default to a table without modifying the rows already written

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql 11 db with a table that has 70M+ rows. I would like to add an `inserted_on` column with `DEFAULT now()`. However, I would like that default to apply only to rows inserted from this point on (the existing rows should have NULL). Is there a way to do this?

I want to leave the NULLs there for a couple of reasons:

- The time (and downtime) it will take to rewrite the whole table
- The value makes no sense for previously-inserted rows, so I want to keep it as NULL

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the default *after* adding, the column existing rows won't be updated.

```
alter table test add created_at timestamp;
alter table test alter created_at set default current_timestamp;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58f9b18bca490fef55630405a1a929c6)

Answer (score 0):

> The time (and downtime) it will take to rewrite the whole table

Since postgres 11, postgres doesn't actually need to rewrite the table when adding a column with a *non-volatile* default value (e.g. not `1` or `current_timestamp` but not `random()`), it will just store the default value in the catalog and use that for rows without a value for the column.

If an old row gets updated, it will use the opportunity to inline the missing default value. Likewise if the entire table gets rewritten (VACUUM FULL).

Comment: Thanks for the answer to an old question. This behavior is unfortunate since in my use case I needed (at the time) for existing rows (from before the table was altered) to keep the `NULL` value.

In any case, I'm long gone from that project :)